# static files settings and directory structures on Django

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

I read Django Manual's [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/reusable-apps/) and I decided to move my static directory.
After I moved static directory and open a page, an error occurs on a browser.

> FileNotFoundError at /myapp/ [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/home/jap/git/mysite/static'

Here is my old directories.

```
mysite/    
|---manage.py    
|---mysite/
|---myapp/
|---static/
    |----test.css
```

Then, here is my new directories.

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
    myapp/
        static/
            myapp/
                test.css
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',
    'debug_toolbar',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

# cf
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

If you give me some pieces of advice, I would be thankful.
Thank you.

Django: 1.9.1
Python: 3.5.1

Comment: What is the value of `BASE_DIR`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Rafeal. My BASE_DIR is "/home/jap/git/mysite". When I move mysite/template/ to mysite/myapp/templates/myapp/, it worked with my settings.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `settings.py`, you define where **Django** should lookup to search for your static files.

Right now, you define the folders it should lookup as

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

which is basically `STATICFILES_DIRS = ("/home/jap/git/mysite/static/",)`

But it its located at `/home/jap/git/mysite/myapp/static/` and not `/home/jap/git/mysite/static/` as configured, because you moved you `static` folder into your app folder.

So you should define your `STATICFILES_DIRS` as

```
APP_DIR = os.path.join(BASEDIR, 'myapp')
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(APP_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

Comment: Ah, really? Manual just mentioned about create static directories on this page(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial06/) and this page(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/) , so I thought all I have to do is just create directories.

Comment: But why my Django cannot recognize /myapp/static/myapp/? My English comprehension is not so good, so maybe I misunderstood the Manual, but Manual doesn't mention about settings.py including APP_DIR.   It only says AppDirectoriesFinder can find /static/ under APP. I guess Django can recognize /myapp/static/myapp/ by default.

Comment: @yamachan It makes no sense to make the `static` folder inside your `app` folder, and then make an `app` folder inside your `static` folder.